# About 'bathroom scale'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Today I learned that the device used for weighing people at home is called '**bathroom scale**' because it is kept in a bathroom in the U.S..

For me, who come from an environment where it wasn't kept in bathroom, It sounds awkward that the device is called '**bathroom scale**'. I'm just saying...

By the way, I have a question about this. Even if their '**bathroom scale**' is not in bathroom actually, nonetheless they still call it 'bathroom scale'?

I think I should have asked this question first.
Are there people(American) who keep it in a different place where is not a bathroom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, bathroom scales appear to be of a norm. I perceive from a quick search online it is a category to all if not most commercial stores when shopping for all scales.

> Even when not precisely located, it may still appropriately be called
>   a bathroom scale.

I believe in a culture differing from that of U.S. the combination of both these words, bathroom and scale, would be more likely to be interpreted as separate from one another.